# elasticsearch term suggest does not return correct result

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm learning elasticsearch term suggestion.
Here is my data:

```
PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {"_id": "1"}}
{"text": ["elastic"]}
{"index": {"_id": "2"}}
{"text": ["elastic", "elastica"]}
{"index": {"_id": "3"}}
{"text": ["elastic", "elastica", "elasticb"]}
{"index": {"_id": "4"}}
{"text": ["elastic", "elastica", "elasticb", "elasticc"]}
```

Here is my search:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "my_suggestion": {
      "text": "elastic",
      "term": {
        "field": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result is:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "suggest": {
    "my_suggestion": [
      {
        "text": "elastic",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 7,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I know the default suggest_mode is `missing`, so "elastic" is not cantained in the result. But why "elastica", "elasticb" and "elasticc" are also not suggested?

Elasticsearch version: 8.10

Comment: Can you show your index mapping?

Comment: @Val, use the default dynamic mapping. Any thing was not configured.  ```{
  "test": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```

Answer (score 0):

the reason `"elastica"`, `"elasticb"`, and `"elasticc"` are not suggested when you search for "elastic" is that the edit distance might be too large for Elasticsearch's default parameters. By default, the term suggester uses a maximum edit distance of 2.
moreover, Elasticsearch also uses the frequency of terms in the index to rank suggestions. If the terms `"elastica"`, `"elasticb"`, and `"elasticc"` are not common, they might not be given as "good" suggestions.

You can set `suggest_mode` to "always" to always get suggestions irrespective of the original text.

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "my_suggestion": {
      "text": "elastic",
      "term": {
        "field": "text",
        "suggest_mode": "always",
        "max_edits": 2,
        "prefix_length": 6
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the definition of Damerau–Levenshtein distance algorithm (which Elastic essentially claims to be their default), it's pretty evident that the distance between "elastic" & "elastic.+" couldn't be more than 1. Simply _not possible_ (in case of correct implementation, indeed). Hence your point of "distance might be too large" is moot at best.